# How do I use knockout to display values of selected checkboxes without foreach?

Tags: javascript, checkbox, knockout.js

Given a list of checkboxes with values equal to a person's name, I am trying to get them added to a knockout observableArray. How can I add a person to the observableArray when someone clicks on a checkbox?

For the HTML, I have the following:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" value="John" data-bind="clicked: addPerson"><span >John</span>

            <input type="checkbox" value="Allen" data-bind="clicked: addPerson"><span>Allen</span>

        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
<hr/>
<div data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(selectedPeople)"></div>
```

Then the knockout javascript is as follows:

```
var viewModel= function () {
    var self = this;
    self.people = ko.observableArray();
    self.selectedPeople = ko.observableArray();
    self.addPerson = function(value){
        self.selectedPeople.push(value);
        return true;
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

I would have thought that the names would be printed as I clicked on them. What am I doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/justinnafe/WHG9x/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forked and updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ivan_Srb/Dn6eH/4/). You could use `computed` for solve you problem. Also, you made mistake with bindings applying and checkbox bindings (you should use `checked` binding and there are no reasons to create additional function in this case).

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" value="John" data-bind="checked: selectedPeople"/>
            <span>John</span>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Allen" data-bind="checked: selectedPeople"/>
            <span>Allen</span>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
<hr/>
<div data-bind="text: displayedPeople"></div>
```

JS:

```
var viewModel= function () {
    var self = this;
    self.selectedPeople = ko.observableArray();
    self.displayedPeople = ko.computed(function() {
        var str = "";
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.selectedPeople(), function(item) {
            str += item + " ";
        });
        return str;
    });
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```